# Can I export comments from adobe to word/excel with hyperlinks?

Tags: excel, pdf, ms-word

I know how to export pdf comments which I can open it with notepad, but I cannot see hyperlinks (after clicking on comment pdf file is opened and I see on which page comment is) Is it possible to create something like that?

I have googled  a lot and I cannot find my answer.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Well I know its weird to answer my question but what I have done- I created content in word, exported to pdf, merged two pdfs together and I add links in my content.